# Insert with Ajax BeginForm

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am doing insert operation with Ajax BeginForm. The operation was successful, but the message returned is `{"result":true,"message":"Customer updated successfully."}` in a new view.
I want to capture the message returned from the controller with iztoast, but even if I write the function, I cannot catch it and there is no error in the console.

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Customer(Customers customers)
    {
        if(customers.crud_type == "insert")
        {
            ModelState.Remove("Customers.musteri_id");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    bool isSuccess = customerService.InsertCustomer(customers);
                    if (isSuccess)
                    {
                        return Json(new { result = true, message = "Müşteri başarıyla eklendi." });
                    }
                    ....
```

AjaxBeginForm :

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customers", "Customer", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "customerSuccess" }))
                {

                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.musteri_id, new { id = "customer_id" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.crud_type, new { id = "crud_type" })

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Müşteri Adı</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriAd, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerNameInput", maxlength = 25, required = "required" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Müşteri Soyadı</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriSoyad, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerSurnameInput", maxlength = 20, required = "required" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Telefon Numarası</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriTel, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerPhoneInput",  required = "required" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
                }
```

Js :

```
 function customerSuccess(data) {    
        iziToast.success({
            title: 'Başarılı',
            message: 'Müşteri başarıyla kaydedildi: ',
            position: 'topRight'
        });
```